# Separating two different string format in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to know if someone can help me with separating two different strings properly.

Dataset:

```
my_series = pd.Series([["asd", "#ghj"],["qwe"],["dsa", "#asd"],["poi"]])
```

My Code:

```
category1 = []
category2 = []

for word_list in my_series:
    for v in word_list:
        if "#" not in v:
            category1.append({v : 1})
        else:
            category2.append({v : 1})
```

Category1 [Out]:

```
[{'asd': 1}, {'qwe': 1}, {'dsa': 1}, {'poi': 1}]
```

Category2 [Out]:

```
[{'#ghj': 1}, {'#asd': 1}]
```

Expecting

Category2 [Out]:

```
[{'#ghj': 1}, {"No category 2" : 1}, {'#asd': 1}, {"No category 2" : 1}]
```

Comment: what ist `a` in your `for` statement?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it should be my_series

Comment: Will you ever get `[ ["asd", "#ghj"], ["#qwe"], ["dsa", "#asd"], ["poi"] ]` in the data?

Comment: @gregory, what do you mean by getting? these are just dummy data that serves as an example

Comment: @Maku, I'm asking if the data can ever have list of one item belonging sometimes to category 1. Look closely my list above.

Comment: @gregory, oh..I see..to answer your question, using my code, it will not but you can tweak it in a way that it will create a list  before moving to the next index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set flag for checking if list have category two or not.

```html
my_series = [["asd", "#ghj"],["qwe"],["dsa", "#asd"],["poi"]]

category1 = []
category2 = []


for w in my_series:
    category2_flag = False // flag to check category_2 present or not. 
    for v in w:
        if '#' not in v:
            category1.append({v: 1})
        else:
            category2.append({v: 1})
            category2_flag = True

    if not category2_flag:
        category2.append({"No category 2": 1})

print(category1)
print(category2)

Output: [{'asd': 1}, {'qwe': 1}, {'dsa': 1}, {'poi': 1}]
[{'#ghj': 1}, {'No category 2': 1}, {'#asd': 1}, {'No category 2': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

zip_longest's fillvalue may work nicely here:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
l = [["asd", "#ghj"],["qwe"],["dsa", "#asd"],["poi"]]

cat1 = list(zip_longest(*l))[0]
cat2 = list(zip_longest(*l, fillvalue='No category 2'))[1]

category1 = [ {x:1} for x in cat1]
category2 = [ {x:1} for x in cat2]
```

output:

```
In: category1
Out: [{'asd': 1}, {'qwe': 1}, {'dsa': 1}, {'poi': 1}]

In: category2
Out: [{'#ghj': 1}, {'No category 2': 1}, {'#asd': 1}, {'No category 2': 1}]
```